# Must declare the scalar variable "@imgPicture"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

super newbie on ASP.Net, and sorry if this has been asked countless times, i have read a lot of the answers to this similar problem here and on google too but i can't find a solution that applies to my code, i want to save the image url into the database, this is the code that isn't working:

```
if (imgPicture.ImageUrl != null)
                {
                    String strConn = "Data Source=TOSHI;Initial Catalog=prueba;Integrated Security=True";
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    string strQuery = "Insert into curriculum (imagen) values      (@imgPicture)";
                    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagen", imgPicture.ImageUrl);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
```

On the cmd.parameters i also tried

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("imagen", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = imgPicture.ImageUrl;
```

But neither worked

Edit: The name of the field on the database is imagen, the image field on the ASP is imgPicture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong name for the parameter.  It should be `@imgPicture`, from the query:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgPicture", imgPicture.ImageUrl);
```

**Update**

Based on the comments to this question, I think the contents of this entire `if` block can be removed and you can place the following into the main insert:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgPicture", (imgPicture.ImageUrl == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)imgPicture.ImageUrl));
```

You will also need to add imagen to the end of the list of columns to insert in the query, and @imgPicture to the parameters.

Comment: I'm getting this one: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Nombre', table 'prueba.dbo.Curriculum'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.  Even if i write something on the column Nombre (is the only column in my table that cannot be null)

Comment: Your insert query needs to specify values for all of your NOT NULL columns.  Can't tell you the full answer given the context of your question, but at least: "Insert into curriculum (imagen, Nombre) values      (@imgPicture, @Nombre)", followed by cmd.Parameters.AddWithWalue("@Nombre", number);

Comment: The insert nombre is working, but is declared in another part of the code (using an sqldatasource), if i remove the code i paste on my first question the page works fine, saves all the textboxes into the database, but, when i add the code to save the image url into the database is when doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for the help but no, update is not what i need, what i'm doing is a profile for the users, they upload the picture, and is show in the image field, fill all the textboxes and dropdowns with their info, and when they click the submit button the information is stored into the database, and when they do that i also want that the imageurll goes into the database too

Comment: Like my update?  Can't give you an exact, again, I would need more context.

Comment: First, needs an extra ) hehe and, DBNull.Value: imgPicture.ImageUrl gives me this: "Type of conditional expression cannot be determinated because there is not implicit conversion between "system.dbnull" and "string", but the idea of the IF inside the line is really good ;)

Comment: Nice catch.  Always forget about that pesky DBNull.Value thing. :)  Edited.

Comment: Duuude!! there is some progress!! now i get this PropertyName must be set to a valid property name of the control named 'imgPicture' in ControlParameter 'imgPicture'.i guess i'm doing it wrong with this <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="imgPicture" DefaultValue="" Name="imgPicture" />

Comment: Way out of scope for the question now...  Why don't you work on it a bit and post a new question with your updated code if you can't figure it out?

Comment: You are right, thank you so much for your help, gonna read about the property name and see if i can find something and get an idea how to fix it!! THANK YOU!! :D

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this has nothing to do with asp.net and everything to do with your query.

Your query is:

```
Insert into curriculum (imagen) values      (@imgPicture)
```

which defines the parameter `@imgPicture`.

Then you are adding a parameter called `@imagen` (which will be ignored), but *more importantly not adding the parameter `@imgPicture`*.

Are you sure you didn't mean `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgPicture", imgPicture.ImageUrl);`?

Comment: No, because the field on the database is named imagen, the image field on the asp code is named imgPicture, that's why they are named different

Comment: @Ivelisse it doesn't matter what the database column is called; that isn't the problem; the problem is that you've used `@imgPicture` without any declaration

Comment: When i add that instead of the line i have i get Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Nombre', table 'prueba.dbo.Curriculum'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated. and using my line at least i can save the columns into the database except the imagen url column gets saved

Comment: @Ivelisse that has already been explained at least once. When doing an INSERT, you need to supply values for all non-null, non-default-value, non-implicit (identity/timetamp/etc) columns. You haven't provided a value for `Nombre`; so **supply one**

Answer (score 2):

Your query is this:

```
string strQuery = "Insert into curriculum (imagen) values (@imgPicture)";
```

where you are declaring `@imgPicture` as your variable.

You need to use that variable in your code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@imgPicture", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = imgPicture.ImageUrl;
```